# WFFM form submitting multiple times

Tags: asp.net, forms, sitecore

When i submit my WFFM forms i can see by two calls going from network,

On my QA environment its working fine but in my PROD its failed.

Please let me know , possible case for this issue

[image]

My exception log below

> 6840 06:57:02 ERROR The anti-forgery cookie token and form field token
>   do not match. Exception: System.Web.Mvc.HttpAntiForgeryException
>   Message: The anti-forgery cookie token and form field token do not
>   match. Source: System.Web.WebPages    at
>   System.Web.Helpers.AntiXsrf.TokenValidator.ValidateTokens(HttpContextBase
>   httpContext, IIdentity identity, AntiForgeryToken sessionToken,
>   AntiForgeryToken fieldToken)    at
>   System.Web.Helpers.AntiXsrf.AntiForgeryWorker.Validate(HttpContextBase
>   httpContext, String cookieToken, String formToken)    at
>   Sitecore.Forms.Mvc.Controllers.Filters.WffmValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute.OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext
>   filterContext)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAuthorizationFilters(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.b__19(AsyncCallback
>   asyncCallback, Object asyncState)
>
> 6840 06:57:02 WARN  [WFFM] CurrentSession  is not initialized 6840
>   06:57:02 WARN  Web Forms for Marketers: an exception 'The anti-forgery
>   cookie token and form field token do not match.' has occured while
>   trying to execute an action ''. 9292 06:57:04 ERROR There was an
>   attempt to do multiple submits within a time interval, specified in
>   the "WFM.LimitMultipleSubmits.IntervalInSeconds" setting! Exception:
>   System.Security.SecurityException Message: There was an attempt to do
>   multiple submits within a time interval, specified in the
>   "WFM.LimitMultipleSubmits.IntervalInSeconds" setting! Source:
>   Sitecore.Forms.Mvc    at
>   Sitecore.Forms.Mvc.Controllers.Filters.WffmLimitMultipleSubmitsAttribute.OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext
>   filterContext)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAuthorizationFilters(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.b__19(AsyncCallback
>   asyncCallback, Object asyncState)
>
> 9292 06:57:04 WARN  [WFFM] CurrentSession  is not initialized 9292
>   06:57:04 WARN  Web Forms for Marketers: an exception 'There was an
>   attempt to do multiple submits within a time interval, specified in
>   the "WFM.LimitMultipleSubmits.IntervalInSeconds" setting!' has occured
>   while trying to execute an action ''. ManagedPoolThread #7 06:57:42
>   INFO  Health.PrivateBytes: 905,527,296

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally issue solved by removed caching on WFFM forms at component level as well as in site definition too. 
(But now seeking how do i cache a page alone without caching WFFM forms)